# Unable to install biopython package

Tags: python, windows-7, biopython

I get the following error when I installed `biopython 1.63` package :

```
building 'Bio.cpairwise2' 
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

I tried all the answers in: [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat) but no thing change, I get the same error:`Unable to find vcvarsall.bat` 
can some one help me?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you originally tried to install that package, you'll most likely need to install the Windows binary instead:

http://biopython.org/wiki/Download

There are some Python packages that need a C compiler like in Visual Studio, or MingW (especially if you install from a package installer - like pip or easy_install). These C compilers can be a pain to set up if you are new to them.

Comment: yes, I installed binary version but when I want to use alignment package(clustalw, muscle...), I get  errors, so I dis-install it , and I try to install biopython from package.

Comment: You may need to give some more context on specifically how you are trying to install those packages. There might be more information in the [biopython installation PDF](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/install/Installation.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the biopython package from this link: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#biopython

Cheers!